# Finish() or moveTaskToBack() doesn't work

Tags: android, android-activity, background, task, activity-finish

I'm trying to put an activity in the background or simply kill it. I'm creating the activity inside a runnable, because I need to wait 2 seconds before it opens:

```
case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
            long user_logged = AppSettings.getLoggedUserSQLiteID(context);
            if (user_logged != 0) {
                final Handler h = new Handler();
                Runnable r1 = new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        String phoneNr = inte.getStringExtra("incoming_number");
                        Intent phonecall = new Intent(ctx, PhoneCall.class);
                        phonecall.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        phonecall.putExtra("phone_number", phoneNr);
                        ctx.startActivity(phonecall);
                    }
                };
                h.postDelayed(r1, 2000); // 1 second delay
            }
break;
```

In the button I specify the method to run on click, like `android:onClick="acceptCall"`:

```
public void acceptCall(View v) {

    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("input keyevent " + Integer.toString(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Runtime.exec(String) had an I/O problem, try to fall back
        String enforcedPerm = "android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED";
        Intent btnDown = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON).putExtra(
                Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
                        KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
        Intent btnUp = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON).putExtra(
                Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP,
                        KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));

        this.sendOrderedBroadcast(btnDown, enforcedPerm);
        this.sendOrderedBroadcast(btnUp, enforcedPerm);

        super.finish();

    }
}
```

To finish, or put it in the background, I tried these lines of code:

```
super.finish();
super.moveTaskToBack(true);
this.finish();
this.moveTaskToBack(true);
```

However, none of them seems to work for me. Can anyone help me understand why?

Answer (score 0):

In default case to kill activity, we should use:

MyActivity is your activity.

```
MyActivity.this.finish();
```

//try to kill your activity after this line of your code:

```
ctx.startActivity(phonecall);
```

Comment: But the first block of code its just a class(listener) that `extends BroadcastReceiver`. Its not a activity.
Altought its starts the activity called `PhoneCall`.